# How can I read how many pixels an image has in Python

Tags: python, pixel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check dimensions of all images in a directory using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507084/how-to-check-dimensions-of-all-images-in-a-directory-using-python)

I was wondering if somebody knows how can I read an image total amount of pixels in a python sript. Could you provide and example?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507084/how-to-check-dimensions-of-all-images-in-a-directory-using-python

Comment: If this is a dupe, it's far more useful than the original.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

here is an example:

```
from PIL import Image

def get_num_pixels(filepath):
    width, height = Image.open(filepath).size
    return width*height

print(get_num_pixels("/path/to/my/file.jpg"))
```

Comment: While not incorrect, `open(filepath)` is not required - `Image.open()` will accept just the filename.

Comment: @mhawke I inserted the filename of the file located in my project directory, but I still get `unresolved file reference` error.

Answer (score 6):

Use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to load the image. The total number of pixels will be its width multiplied by its height.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example that you've asked for:

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path

filename = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'image', 'file')
img = Image.open(filename)
width, height = img.size
print "Dimensions:", img.size, "Total pixels:", width * height
```

Comment: what if i want to split total pixel in R,G and B  ?????

Comment: @M.D.P: multiply by 3? I am not sure what you mean. Each pixel would have a component for R, G, and B.

Answer (score 1):

PIL, the Python Imaging Library can help you get this info from image's metadata.