# Get image size without downloading it in Python

Tags: python, image, url

How can I get dimensions of image without actually downloading it? Is it even possible?
I have a list of urls of images and I want to assign width and size to it.

I know there is a way of doing it locally ([How to check dimensions of all images in a directory using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507084/how-to-check-dimensions-of-all-images-in-a-directory-using-python)), but I don't want to download all the images.

Edit:

Following ed. suggestions, I edited the code. I came up with [this code](http://codepad.org/dC1RSwxi). Not sure weather it downloads whole file or just a part (as I wanted).

Comment: it's usually some header in the beginning of the file, so you can download only few bytes. e.g. 6 bytes will be enough to get dimensions of jpeg: http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html

Answer (score 24):

I found the solution on [this site](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-image-size.htm) to work well:

```
import urllib
import ImageFile

def getsizes(uri):
    # get file size *and* image size (None if not known)
    file = urllib.urlopen(uri)
    size = file.headers.get("content-length")
    if size: size = int(size)
    p = ImageFile.Parser()
    while 1:
        data = file.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        p.feed(data)
        if p.image:
            return size, p.image.size
            break
    file.close()
    return size, None

print getsizes("http://www.pythonware.com/images/small-yoyo.gif")
# (10965, (179, 188))
```

Comment: Where does `ImageFile` comes from?

Comment: PIL -- python imaging library

Comment: Take care with the file descriptor in this code: if the image size is retrieved the file is not closed.

Comment: Can you elaborate @IvanDePazCenteno? Wouldn't a "file.close()" before the return size, p.image.size fix that? And also, is this even a problem?

Comment: @FabianBosler yes, adding a `file.close()` before that line would do the trick, even though I would recommend using the `with` keyword to manage it, as it is a [good practice](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Definitely yes, it is a problem. Not closing allocated resources will potentially become a disaster in certain contexts, for example in big loops. An allocated resource should always be closed, even if the OS or the interpreter itself can get rid of it.

Comment: It is giving me following error. Have you used any other imports?
"AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'"

Comment: @ShagunPruthi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969726/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlopen

Comment: @jedierikb : Gotcha! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Does `file.read(1024)` mean that it downloads only 1024 bytes instead of the whole image?

Answer (score 16):

This is based on ed's answer mixed with other things I found on the web.  I ran into the same issue as grotos with .read(24).  Download getimageinfo.py from [here](https://gist.github.com/bmamouri/55ac6bfa7ba5eee03da2eb9e4f7469d9) and download ReSeekFile.py from [here](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/05/18/updated_reseekfile.html).

```
import urllib2
imgdata = urllib2.urlopen(href)
image_type,width,height = getimageinfo.getImageInfo(imgdata)
```

Modify getimageinfo as such...

```
import ReseekFile

def getImageInfo(datastream):
    datastream = ReseekFile.ReseekFile(datastream)
    data = str(datastream.read(30))

#Skipping to jpeg

# handle JPEGs
elif (size >= 2) and data.startswith('\377\330'):
    content_type = 'image/jpeg'
    datastream.seek(0)
    datastream.read(2)
    b = datastream.read(1)
    try:
        while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
            while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = datastream.read(1)
            while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = datastream.read(1)
            if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
                datastream.read(3)
                h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", datastream.read(4))
                break
            else:
                datastream.read(int(struct.unpack(">H", datastream.read(2))[0])-2)
            b = datastream.read(1)
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)
    except struct.error:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Nice work.  I also ran into the same issue with the otherwise helpful response from ed

Comment: The source code for `getimageinfo.py` is not available anymore. Here is the code for anyone who is looking for it in future: https://gist.github.com/bmamouri/55ac6bfa7ba5eee03da2eb9e4f7469d9

Answer (score 16):

This is just a Python 3+ adaptation of an earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16379179/2628402).

```
from urllib import request as ulreq
from PIL import ImageFile
 
def getsizes(uri):
    # get file size *and* image size (None if not known)
    file = ulreq.urlopen(uri)
    size = file.headers.get("content-length")
    if size: 
        size = int(size)
    p = ImageFile.Parser()
    while True:
        data = file.read(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        p.feed(data)
        if p.image:
            return size, p.image.size
            break
    file.close()
    return(size, None)
```

Comment: you should obviously use finally for file.close (or better context manager) and not bother anyone with using "break" after return.

Answer (score 10):

If you're willing to download the first 24 bytes of each file, then [this function](http://code.google.com/p/bfg-pages/source/browse/trunk/pages/getimageinfo.py) (mentioned in johnteslade's answer to the question you mention) will work out the dimensions.

That's probably the least downloading necessary to do the job you want.

```
import urllib2
start = urllib2.urlopen(image_url).read(24)
```

Edit (1):

In the case of jpeg files it seems to need more bytes. You could edit the function so that instead of reading a StringIO.StringIO(data) it instead reads the file handle from urlopen. Then it will read exactly as much of the image as it needs to find out the width and height.

Comment: Using this solution, especially .read(24), breaks that script. All works when I use read().

Comment: It's basically the same as an example in the python docs (http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). What error do you get using (24)? Just using read() (I guess you know) will download the whole file...

Comment: If I run with read(24) ther is some error in getImageInfo function: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'w' referenced before assignment

Comment: Hmm. Try running it with read(50) and see if it works. I think the error must be coming from the jpeg part of the function, so maybe it needs a few more bytes.

Comment: It is the same. I think it only works with read(X), where X is so large that it covers the whole file.

Answer (score 7):

Since [getimageinfo.py](http://code.google.com/p/bfg-pages/source/browse/trunk/pages/getimageinfo.py) mentioned above doesn't work in Python3. Pillow is used instead of it.

Pillow can be found in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0), or installed by using pip: `pip install pillow`.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import requests
hrefs = ['https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg','https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3920/15008465772_383e697089_m.jpg','https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_86abb8c56f_m.jpg']
RANGE = 5000
for href in hrefs:
    req  = requests.get(href,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla5.0(Google spider)','Range':'bytes=0-{}'.format(RANGE)})
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(req.content))

    print(im.size)
```

Comment: Doesn't this actually download the image? I believe that's what OP is trying to avoid

Comment: I'd suggest to use requests' session to reuse TCP connection and use plain HTTP instead of HTTPS if possible. It may dramatically increase performance in some cases.

Answer (score 6):

## By using the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library:

**To get the image size in bytes:**

Only by getting the headers data from the website: (without downloading the image)

```
import requests

url = r"https://www.sulitest.org/files/source/Big%20image%20HD/elyx.png"

size = requests.get(url, stream = True).headers['Content-length']
print(size)
## output: 437495

## to see what other headers data you can get:
allheaders = requests.get(url, stream = True).headers
print(allheaders)
```

**To get the image (Width, Height):**

We have to download part of the image and let an image library read the image header and retrieve/parse the (Width, Height). here i'm using [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/).

```
import requests
from PIL import ImageFile

resume_header = {'Range': 'bytes=0-2000000'}    ## the amount of bytes you will download
data = requests.get(url, stream = True, headers = resume_header).content

p = ImageFile.Parser()
p.feed(data)    ## feed the data to image parser to get photo info from data headers
if p.image:
    print(p.image.size) ## get the image size (Width, Height)
## output: (1400, 1536)
```

Comment: This worked like charm!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it directly, but there's a workaround for that. If the files are present on the server, then implement the API endpoint that takes image name as an argument and returns the size.

But if the files are on the different server, you've got no other way but to download the files.

Comment: Based on the other answer for this question this seems to be an incorrect assertion.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus No, all the other answers just suggest downloading the image (or parts of the image). This answer is the **most** correct, but the others are valid work-arounds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment, so this is as an answer:

Use a get query with the header

```
"Range": "bytes=0-30"
```

And then simply use

http://code.google.com/p/bfg-pages/source/browse/trunk/pages/getimageinfo.py

If you use python's "requests", it's simply

```
r = requests.get(image_url, headers={
    "Range": "bytes=0-30"
})
image_info = get_image_info(r.content)
```

This fixes ed.'s answer and doesn't have any other dependencies (like ReSeekFile.py).

Comment: The provided url is invalid

Answer (score 1):

My fixed "getimageInfo.py", work with Python 3.4+, try it, just great!

```
import io
import struct
import urllib.request as urllib2

def getImageInfo(data):
    data = data
    size = len(data)
    #print(size)
    height = -1
    width = -1
    content_type = ''

    # handle GIFs
    if (size >= 10) and data[:6] in (b'GIF87a', b'GIF89a'):
        # Check to see if content_type is correct
        content_type = 'image/gif'
        w, h = struct.unpack(b"<HH", data[6:10])
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)

    # See PNG 2. Edition spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/)
    # Bytes 0-7 are below, 4-byte chunk length, then 'IHDR'
    # and finally the 4-byte width, height
    elif ((size >= 24) and data.startswith(b'\211PNG\r\n\032\n')
          and (data[12:16] == b'IHDR')):
        content_type = 'image/png'
        w, h = struct.unpack(b">LL", data[16:24])
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)

    # Maybe this is for an older PNG version.
    elif (size >= 16) and data.startswith(b'\211PNG\r\n\032\n'):
        # Check to see if we have the right content type
        content_type = 'image/png'
        w, h = struct.unpack(b">LL", data[8:16])
        width = int(w)
        height = int(h)

    # handle JPEGs
    elif (size >= 2) and data.startswith(b'\377\330'):
        content_type = 'image/jpeg'
        jpeg = io.BytesIO(data)
        jpeg.read(2)
        b = jpeg.read(1)
        try:
            while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
                while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
                while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
                if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
                    jpeg.read(3)
                    h, w = struct.unpack(b">HH", jpeg.read(4))
                    break
                else:
                    jpeg.read(int(struct.unpack(b">H", jpeg.read(2))[0])-2)
                b = jpeg.read(1)
            width = int(w)
            height = int(h)
        except struct.error:
            pass
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return content_type, width, height



#from PIL import Image
#import requests
#hrefs = ['http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3894/15008518202_b016d7d289_m.jpg','https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3920/15008465772_383e697089_m.jpg','https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3902/14985871946_86abb8c56f_m.jpg']
#RANGE = 5000
#for href in hrefs:
    #req  = requests.get(href,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla5.0(Google spider)','Range':'bytes=0-{}'.format(RANGE)})
    #im = getImageInfo(req.content)

    #print(im)
req = urllib2.Request("http://vn-sharing.net/forum/images/smilies/onion/ngai.gif", headers={"Range": "5000"})
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
#f = open("D:\\Pictures\\1.jpg", "rb")
print(getImageInfo(r.read()))
# Output: >> ('image/gif', 50, 50)
#print(getImageInfo(f.read()))
```

Source code: http://code.google.com/p/bfg-pages/source/browse/trunk/pages/getimageinfo.py

Comment: Hey this is very interesting. Just curious what the `RANGE` variable is doing... does that limit how many bytes get downloaded?

Comment: This wasn't working with many JPEGs for me. I found an alternative function (posted as answer)

Comment: Failed to work on many files. First 5Kb isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

The shortest code I have come up with downloads only the first 1024 bytes. This can be set lower if you need it to but could give problems with some image types

```
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from PIL import Image
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None # My problem had really big images

def get_image_size_from_url(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    r = response.read(1024)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(r))
    return img.size
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

url = 'http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3488/4051378654_238ca94313.jpg'

img_data = requests.get(url).content    
im = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
print (im.size)
```

Comment: part of the question was "without actually downloading it". `requests.get(url).content` will download the image.