# Initializing Python class

Tags: python, oop

I am newbie in object-oriented design.

I try to incorporate a python function into my **init** . (Function works, as  [I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460218/get-image-size-wihout-downloading-it-in-python)).

Here is my code:

```
import struct
import urllib2
import StringIO


class wallpaper:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.content_type = ''
        self.height = 0
        self.width = 0
        image = urllib2.urlopen(self.url)
        data = str(image.read(2))
        if  data.startswith('\377\330'):
            self.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
            jpeg = StringIO.StringIO(data)
            jpeg.read(2)
            b = jpeg.read(1)
            try:
                while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
                    while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
                    while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = jpeg.read(1)
                    if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
                        jpeg.read(3)
                        h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", jpeg.read(4))
                        break
                    else:
                        jpeg.read(int(struct.unpack(">H", jpeg.read(2))[0])-2)
                        b = jpeg.read(1)
                    self.width = int(w)
                    self.height = int(h)
            except struct.error:
                pass
            except ValueError:
                pass


x = wallpaper('http://i.imgur.com/rapwX.jpg')
print x.url, "\t", x.content_type,"\t", x.height,"\t", x.width
```

The problem is that I cannot initialize  height and width properties (they are equal 0).

Where is the problem?

Edit:

I've found problem, here is [solution](http://codepad.org/tV01oz79). Thanks for your hints.

One more question: is my approach proper as far as OOP rules are concerned? Should I compute width/height in **init** or create other method (eg. size, or so)?

Comment: Instead of playing with the binary data your self, you can use the (Python Image Library)[http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/] to handle all the low-level stuff.

Comment: Why do you ignore any ValueError? (and strtuct.error?)

Answer (score 3):

You're only reading 2 bytes into `data`.

Comment: But that works well - you don't have to download the whole image to get its dimensions.

Comment: Do you actually believe that? Have you tried reading the code?

Comment: I did only some testing with large images (about 4MB) - this script is as responsive as with smaller ones. I know this is not the best way to check it, but I don't have other tools to measure precisely.

Answer (score 1):

It will be difficult to determine the problem if you simply ignore exceptions:

```
    except struct.error:
        pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

At least you should print the error messages:

```
    except struct.error as exc:
        print str(exc)
    except ValueError as exc:
        print str(exc)
```

This way you should be able to debug your code and thus solve your problem.

Of course, I assume that the indentation is correct in your actual code.

Comment: While this is true, the problem is not that an exception is being raised.

Answer (score 1):

If this condition

```
ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3
```

is true at the first iteration of the outer `while` , you break out of the loop before assigning `self.width` and `self.height`. Maybe you meant to indent the two assignments one level less than they are in your code?