# Given a list of images, how do I programmatically find their h and v size?

Tags: arrays

Given a list of images, you can manually send them to Chrome which will report their horizontal and vertical pixel numbers.

This can take hours in the middle of what should be a programmable task.
How?

Again, manual works just fine but takes too long.
Need to send a list to something that returns sizes.

This is part of using .PDF to replace .xsl. Details at http://www.tinaja.com/whtnu19.shtml

Eliminate several hours of manual programming from what should be a fully automated process. Must work on all flavors of images.

Comment: What language are you programming in? Where are these images stored? E.g. are they just a bunch of files on disk?

Comment: Presently prefer a postscript solution, but ANY way of inputting a list of filenames and getting the resolutions back programatically would be welcome. Images are stored on my website and on host PC and their names are derived from sitemap_images.xml

Comment: The big picture at https://www.tinaja.com/whtnu19.shtml#d10.29.19

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a programming environment to do this, I think you can do it in the OS. For example:

- Windows: [Get image file dimensions in .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855048/get-image-file-dimensions-in-bat-file)
- On a Mac: [Get pixel dimensions of a PNG on my Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/273059/get-pixel-dimensions-of-a-png-on-my-mac)
- Linux: [Shell command to get pixel size of an image](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75635/shell-command-to-get-pixel-size-of-an-image)

I'm a Python person, so I'd probably use [`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (`from PIL import Image; img = Image.open('image.jpg'); print(img.size)`) but it's straightforward to do in most modern languages, e.g. see this question for a JavaScript solution: [How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Which approach you use depends on where you're getting the rest of your workflow done.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that exactly what I needed was mediainfo. Two alternatives are .bat files and a powershell.

Thanks for your help.
Follow the progress at http://www.tinaja.com/whtnu19.shtml