# Get TIFF image dimensions without using add in Python modules

Tags: python, tiff, python-2.5

I would like to use Python to extract the dimensions of a TIFF image. That will return the width and height in pixels.

The same question was asked here

[How to extract dimensions for Jpegs , Png and Gif files with python with using add in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032642/how-to-obtain-image-size-using-standard-python-class-without-using-external-lib)

The answer above does not address tiff files.

I cannot add an modules at work I need a solution that will not use any add in modules.

I have found the specifications listed here

[file format of tiff](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/egff.htm#TIFF.FO)

it states that Tiff header is 8 bytes long

The first two bytes are either ii or MM depending on the last 4 bytes are the Offset to the IFL(Image file directory). Its inside the IFL that contains the information related to the height and width. But the IFL can be a variable size, dependent on what is inside it. Also if there are several images. The last four bytes of the IFL will be a offset to the next IFL.

The adobe specifications for TIFF are here: [tiff 6.0 version adobe](https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf)  - It shows an example of the tiff structure on page 20.

I was wondering if someone might have had some experience with this . I struggle to understand , how to get inside the IFL and extract the information I like

Comment: So, extract those bytes and interpret them, what's the problem? The `struct` standard module or `ctypes.Structure` class are stock tools to work with C structures in Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C-like structures in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988/c-like-structures-in-python)