# Python - getting image size with function returns error

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, pygame, size

I am quite new to python and I was trying to get the height of an image using a function copied from another post, so that I can correctly position the image in the window for a game I am making with PyGame. Any ideas?

Code:

http://pastebin.com/atZ6vbZQ
(get_image_size copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032642/how-to-obtain-image-size-using-standard-python-class-without-using-external-lib))

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Game/game.py", line 67, in 
    displayCar((display_width / 2), (display_height - (get_image_size(Lightning).height)))
  File "Game/game.py", line 22, in get_image_size
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fhandle:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, pygame.Surface found

Comment: why don't you use `Lightning.get_rect()` to get image size (and position) - ie. `Lightning.get_rect().width`.

Comment: BTW: `get_image_size(filename)` expects `file name` but you use `Lightning` which is `pygame.Surface` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_image_size(fname)` expects `file name` but you use `Lightning` which is `pygame.Surface()` object

---

But [pygame.Surface()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.htmla) is very useful you can get its size (and position) as [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object

```
Lightning_rect = Lightning.get_rect()
```

and then you have image size and position

```
Lightning_rect.width
Lightning_rect.height
Lightning_rect.x
Lightning_rect.y
Lightning_rect.left
Lightning_rect.right
Lightning_rect.top
Lightning_rect.bottom

Lightning_rect.center
```

etc.

You can change position using

```
Lightning_rect.x = new_x
Lightning_rect.y = new_y
```

or

```
Lightning_rect.topleft = (new_x, new_y)
```

And draw/blit

```
gameDisplay.blit(Lightning, Lightning_rect)
```

if you want to center image on screen then

```
gameDisplay_rect = gameDisplay.get_rect()

Lightning_rect.center = gameDisplay_rect.center
```

BWT: you can use Rect() to check collision with another Rect() (`pygame.Rect.colliderect`) or point (`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`) - ie. with mouse position to build button.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I added links to Surface and Rect in Pygame doc .