# Is there a function in python 3, that returns a pixel size of .bmp file? (not using special library)

Tags: python-3.x, bitmap, pixel, bmp, python-3.9

I have a white-small.bmp file (32 x 32 px) and i need to get its pixel size to use it later in code. I wonder if there is a function for example:
`get_size_of_bmp('white-small.bmp')` which returns int: 32*32 which is `1024` or list `[32, 32]`,
(1024 is enough information for my application)

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function that comes to my mind, but there is a [library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that enables you to get this information easly.

```
image = PIL.Image.open("image_name.bmp")
width, height = image.size
```

Comment: I cant use PIL library

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032642/how-to-obtain-image-size-using-standard-python-class-without-using-external-lib