# How to get sizes of files in a folder

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and I am trying to figure out how to check the sizes of pictures I have in a folder. After  that I want to proceed only if the filesize is larger than 10kb.

Answer (score 1):

you can use os module

```
import os
b = os.path.getsize("filename")
print(b)
```

The size will be in bytes

Comment: But this would require me to enter each file name individually if I am not mistaken. What I want is to enter the folder with the pictures, loop over them and give me the size of each picture.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507084/how-to-check-dimensions-of-all-images-in-a-directory-using-python maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
import os


def get_file_size(directory):
"""Returns the `file` size in KB."""
try:
    # print("[+] Getting the size of", file)
    for entry in os.scandir(directory):
        if entry.is_file():
            # if it's a file, use stat() function
            total = int('{:,.0f}'.format(entry.stat().st_size / float(1 << 10)))  #file size in KB
            if total > 10:
                print("This file is greater that 10KB do something ")
except PermissionError:
    # if for whatever reason we can't open the folder, return 0
    return 0
return total
```